# Logging in a page with java that first displays an error and no HTML

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to login in an html web page using java's Jsoup. Problem here is that the web seem to try to log-in first (return's an un-authorized error (pic 1)) and ask credentials later using an alert box (if i'm not mistaken), and for some reason there is nothing in the html file (pic 2):
[image]

[image]

I tried something like this:

```
 Element loginform = doc.getElementById("alert");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("type");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("text"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("password"))
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }
```

I'm not much of an expert in this field so I don't really know what could be wrong. I can't even find any ID for the alertbox anywhere since it's an empty file, CTRL+U returns blank as well...
[image]

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue yet? What's the URL of the page you're trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

It's called Basic Authentication.
Server expects you to send a request with "Authorization" header. The value of this header should start with string `"Basic "` followed by `username` and `password` joined with a colon `:` and base64 encoded.
Example:

```
//import java.util.Base64;

String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String joinedCredentials = username + ":" + password;
String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(joinedCredentials.getBytes());
String authorizationHeaderValue = "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials;

Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL)
     .header("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue)
     .get();
```

Comment: I tried that, added the String variables as global var's and then when the sendPost request is made, I added the Document var, and in return I get Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL=[10.10.100.200/] I also added the user agent there but no prevail :(